# Не работает message_hundler при вызове команды. Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, async-await

**КОД:**

```
@dp.message_handler(Text(equals="Профиль"), commands=["profile"])
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при вводе команды `/profile` - срабатывал `message_hundler`?

p.s. - Пробовал и с `[]`, и без. Результата никакого...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так понимаю вы хотите чтобы при команде profile и при тексте Профиль тригерился данный хендлер?
Думаю вот так нужно.

```
@dp.message_handler(text="Профиль")
@dp.message_handler(commands=["profile"])
async def s(message: types.Message):
    ...
```

То есть ты его двумя декораторами обрабатываешь.

PS. Скобки нужны для перечисления команд, на которые будет тригерится данный хендлер. И можно через запятую их перечислить, но так как вы хотели в один хендлер впихнуть проверку на текст сообщения и на команду, то произошло ничего.

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое. Даже не предполагал, что с декораторами в Aiogram так можно :)

Comment: Пожалуйста, тыкайте галочку для принятия ответа =)